# Centrar grafo Pertersen en jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

Querría saber cómo puedo que el grafo salga recto y no inclinado como está. Lo estoy haciendo con el IDE Jupyter y Python 3.6.

Este es el código:

```
import networkx

gP = { 1: [2,5,6], 2: [3,1,7], 3: [4,2,8], 4: [5,3,9], 5: [1,4,10],6: [1,8,9], 
            7:[2,9,10], 8: [3,10,6], 9: [4,6,7], 10: [5,7,8] }

for k in gP:
    gP[k].append(-1)
    gP[k].append(-2)
gP[-1] = list(range(1,11))
gP[-2] = list(range(1,11))

rH = [8, 3, 4, 5, 10, 7, 2, 1, 6, 9];
g = networkx.Graph()
for k, vs in gP.items():
   for v in vs:
      if v in [-1, -2] or k in [-1, -2]:
          continue
      if abs(rH.index(k) - rH.index(v)) == 1:
          g.add_edge(k,v, color='red', width=1.5)
      else:
          g.add_edge(k,v, color='black', width=0.5)

posicion = networkx.circular_layout(g)
edges = g.edges()
colors = [g[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
width = [g[u][v]['width'] for u,v in edges]
networkx.draw_shell(g, nlist=[range(6,11), range(1,6)], edge_color=colors, width=width, with_labels = True)
```

Muchas gracias.

[image: Grafo que quiero que salga recto y no inclinado como está]

Comment: Hola, la biblioteca que uso para crear el grafo es networkx y el código que utilizo para que me lo muestre es: `networkx.draw_shell(n, nlist = [range(6,11), range(1,6)], node_color = 'y', node_size = 700, edge_color = color, width = ancho, with_labels = True)`

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicación, `n` es `g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que has mostrado hay una línea que dice:

```
posicion = networkx.circular_layout(g)
```

Esta línea sirve para calcular una disposición de los nodos (las coordenadas `x,y` en que deberían dibujarse cada uno de ellos), de modo que queden organizados en forma de círculo.

En realidad esta línea sobra, pues no haces nada después con las posiciones que has calculado, ya que de hecho pintas el grafo siguiendo otra disposición, llamada "shell".  Cuando llamas a la función `draw_shell()`, esta función internamente llama a `networkx.shell_layout()` para calcular dónde iría cada nodo (disponiendolos en este caso en varias capas circulares), y también pinta el resultado.

Podemos separar estas dos operaciones de forma explícita: primero calcular dónde irían los nodos, según una disposición "por capas" (*shell*):

```
posicion = networkx.shell_layout(g, nlist=[range(6,11), range(1,6)])
```

y después pintarlo en esas posiciones (fíjate que ahora uso `draw()` en lugar de `draw_shell()`:

```
[...]
networkx.draw(g, pos=posicion, edge_color=colors, width=width, with_labels = True)
```

El resultado de momento es el mismo que saldría con tu código:

[image: Resultado]

Si hubiera alguna forma de pedir a `networkx.shell_layout()` que los rote las posiciones de los nodos, antes de pedir a `networkx.draw()` que lo dibuje, tendríamos lo que buscas. Por desgracia, las funciones que calculan la disposición de los nodos no admiten ningún parámetro que permita rotar el resultado.

Pero el hacerlo en dos etapas nos permite rotarlo "a mano", por así decir, pues la variable `posiciones` es un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de los nodos (números en este caso) y cuyos valores son las coordenadas `x,y` (en forma de array numpy) donde debe pintarse cada uno.

Podemos por tanto manipular las posiciones de los nodos como nos venga en gana. La siguiente función utiliza álgebra matricial y numpy para girar respecto al origen todos los puntos del grafo, un ángulo dado (en sentido horario, antihorario si el ángulo es negativo):

```
import numpy as np

def rotate_pos(pos, angle):
  newpos={}
  theta = np.radians(angle)
  c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
  R = np.array(((c,-s), (s, c)))
  for k,v in pos.items():
    newpos[k]=np.dot(v,R)
  return newpos
```

Así pues, para rotar a la izquierda tu grafo un ángulo de 360/20 (que es la cantidad necesaria en este caso para que la base del pentágono salga horizontal, en lugar de que uno de sus lados salga vertical), el código sería:

```
networkx.draw(g, pos=rotate_pos(posicion, -360/20),
              edge_color=colors, width=width, with_labels=True)
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Es lo que me faltaba porque quería mostrarlo mejor gráficamente! Gracias por la respuesta y por la rapidez.